# Operador : en consulta JSON en un motor de Base de datos PostgreSQL

Tags: php, json, postgresql

Estoy analizando el código de una aplicación PHP (donde la aplicación está solo programada en PHP) dentro del código se realiza una consulta a la base de datos en `postgresql` donde se utiliza una condición `where algo = :algo`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT uuid, data->\'Field\' as "Field", modified, data->\'externalId\' as "externalId" FROM tablename WHERE contexto = :contexto AND classpath = :classpath
```

donde uuid, data, modified, contexto y classpath son columna de la tabla, y data es un JSON, **mi duda es especifico es que indican los : en las condiciones** `WHERE contexto = :contexto AND classpath = :classpath`

Comment: Todo parece indicar marcadores de nombre, para no usar directamente las variables que manda el usuario y evitar o minimizar la inyección de código, esto forma parte de las sentencias preparadas, posterior con bindParam o un método similar se hace el cambio del marcador de nombre por el valor de la variable que manda el usuario

Comment: Tendrías que mostrar quizas el código, pero el : en los querys se usa habitualmente para no concatenar las variables dentro del string del query.  Con la funcion luego con el método bindParam les das valor a los parametros definidos con :  . Por jemplo bindParam(":classpath",$variable  ) ;